# Is there any resource to explain all decisions made on WordPress?

Tags: core

For example, `<br>`, `<ol type="a">` don't work. Instead of being frustrated each time a feature that should work doesn't work, annoyed that it's an intentional decision, and reluctant to research more even though I do want to know why because once I fix it it's not become a big priority now, I would like to have a page to collect all those decisions and explain why, so I'm more prepared and also understand WordPress more.

Comment: WordPress is 20 years old and open source. No one has a single list of every decision made, let alone the reasons they were made.

Comment: assuming that they're all deliberate decisions! Note that I've seen plenty of `<br>` tags in WordPress post content so it's also possible the decision was not made by the WordPress project and is being enjoyed by many others, or that you have a separate independent problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any resource to explain all decisions made on WordPress?

No, there is none, and it's rare for an open source project to have one, especially one of WordPress' age.

> For example, `<br>`, `<ol type="a">` don't work.

***But they do work,*** and there is even code to explicitly allow them and enable them in the source code of WordPress:

- `<br>`: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.2/src/wp-includes/kses.php#L110
- `<ol type="a">`: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.2/src/wp-includes/kses.php#L367-L369

If you are unable to use these, it is not because WordPress decided to disable them, WordPress allows them. Something else is causing your problems.

If you're curious how it was decided what is in that list, the contents of that list are determined by the security and safety of the respective tags. Post content shouldn't contain anything dangerous such as script tags or things that would allow those to happen, but blocks filters and shortcodes can be used to insert these safely so that embeds and interactive content are still possible. Trac tickets and the commit history are the closest to the decision record you seek, but they will not help you with your current predicament.

Comment: "Something else is causing your problems" – how do I find out that something? // So is it correct that WordPress handles HTML by the whitelist approach (allow what is known as safe) and not the blacklist approach (allow what is not known as unsafe)?

Comment: wp_kses_post filters HTML to a list of allowed tags/attributes, and if you have the `unfiltered_html` capability it ignores that and allows all HTML through, this is only available for administrator roles on single sites (not multisite), and a lot of agencies/enterprise/managed hosts disable it for security reasons and because it lets you put broken HTML in places like post titles. It's more likely somewhere you're filtering kses, or have custom HTML filtering, or are not displaying the content in a standard way, but the scope of what it could be is too big to write an answer

Comment: as for "handles HTML", that implies that the entire page is ran through some sort of system, which isn't the case. Nothing stops you grabbing raw post content and outputting it on the frontend directly via `echo get_post_content();`. WP uses `wp_kses_post` on save _normally_ to prevent dangerous markup being saved in the database, which is a list of allowed tags/attributes, and since there's a limited number of HTML tags with known properties such a list is possible, ignoring web components etc and newer HTML5+ stuff